# How come def processes *args in the call is alway a tuple?

Tags: python, arguments, tuples, function, call-by-value

This is my code. I was observing  data type of args in `def` function.

```
>>> def example(a,b=None,*args,**kwargs):
...   print a, b
...   print args
...   print kwargs
...
>>> example(1,"var",2,3,word="hello")
1 var
(2, 3)
{'word': 'hello'}
>>> _args = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> _kwargs = {"1":1,"2":2,"3":3}
>>> example(1,"var",*_args,**_kwargs)
1 var
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
{'1': 1, '3': 3, '2': 2}
```

When the `2, 3` of actual parameters (arguments) to a function pass as `*arg` of formal parameters; thus, arguments are passed using call by value (where the value is always an object reference, not the value of the object).

`*args` in the *call* expands each element in my sequence (be it tuple or list) into separate parameters. Those separate parameters are then captured again into the `*args` argument, why is it always a `tuple`?

Comment: You also *called* the function with `*args` in the call syntax. That is a separate syntax, mirroring the function signature. Pass in  the list *as one argument* instead, so `example('a', 'b', ['foo', 'bar'])`.

Comment: Do you really understand my question? I doesn't quest how to pass to `*args`.

Comment: All the arguments before a keyword arg and after `a` and `b` will  assumed as `args` and python will return them in a tuple, and when you pass `*_args`  to your function actually you have unpacked your args! if you want to it print a list or ... you can pass your argument within a list like `[2,3]` then the result will be `([2,3],)`.

Comment: `*args` in the *call* expands each element in your sequence (be it tuple or list) into separate parameters. Those separate parameters are then captured again into the `*args` *argument*, which is always a tuple.

Comment: @Pythoneer: if you wanted to pass in a list `args` as a separate argument, don't use `*args` in the call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got it. I doesn't focus args with/without star in different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to know you said `Those separate parameters are then captured again into the *args argument, which is always a tuple.`.  May you more explain?

Comment: @Pythoneer: Sorry, I am having a hard time understanding your English. As a result, I am not confident you understand what I am writing either. I am not sure I can help you out here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know my writing is poor in English, but reading is no problem. I think it is keyword and can solve my problem.